# Adding or multiplying cubic splines obtained with scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline

Tags: scipy, interpolation

I have a function that wants to combine multiple spectra (x,y) with addition and multiplication. For each of those spectra I have cubic spline objects (scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline). When I try to run my function I get this error:

- TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'CubicSpline'

I've searched this site and google for how to operate on type cubic splines (tried to use:

- tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep()
- Function = scipy.interpolate.PPoly.from_spline(tck)

...but I can't understand how to handle and manipulate these objects to be used with mathematical operations.) I can't just add the raw spectra without splines because they don't all share common 'x' values.

I can plot them and integrate them separately, so what form do I need to put them into to use simple math operators (multiply two splines, add splines)?

Comment: I think you will have to select a common `x` for ea spectra, use the cubic spline interpolator to extract the `y` and then operate (+/-) as you desire.

Comment: From the [`CubicSpline` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html): `x = np.linspace(<min>, <max>); y_sum = cs1(x) + cs2(x); y_diff = cs1(x) - cs2(x);` etc.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMikofski, that's exactly it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Mikofski wrote, the objects returned SciPy's interpolating routines cannot be added, or multiplied by a scalar, etc. Their **values** can be  combined, after the splines are evaluated on the same grid.

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
xdata1 = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 3, 5])
ydata1 = np.array([8, 5, 4, 2, 1])
cs1 = CubicSpline(xdata1, ydata1)   # first spline

xdata2 = np.array([-2, 0.5, 1.2, 3, 4])
ydata2 = np.array([4, 5, 7, 8, 7])
cs2 = CubicSpline(xdata2, ydata2)   # second spline

x = np.linspace(max(xdata1.min(), xdata2.min()), min(xdata1.max(), xdata2.max()), 100)
y_sum = cs1(x) + cs2(x) 
plt.plot(x, y_sum)
```

The slightly fussy way in which `x` is defined is to be sure that the range of x fits inside the interval of definition of either spline.